# How to pass data from C++ application to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, pivot

I'm developing a jQuery-based pivot table.

The goal is not a web app but a desktop-based application (C++). In my idea, data is retrieved by the application from the database, then passed to a html page and then showed through the pivot-table plugin.

There is no web server and the web page containing the plugin cannot access to the database.

So, how to pass data in an efficient way? I've seen other questions here on SO around this matter, but I think we're in a different scenario. Of course I can write the data in a txt/xml/js file, but I've experienced that for huge amounts of data, writing down files is costing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add support for the http protocol to your application, and you don't want to write to additional files, then IMO your best bet is to create a wrapping http server for your application. Then the javascript page can access the running wrapper which can talk to your "real" application.

You could create such a server relatively easily in python using the twisted framework, ruby using rails and the bundled webrick server, or the v8 Javascript engine node.js. (I'm sure there's dozens of other options out there too)

Which of there would be best for you will depend a lot on which languages you have experience with and what your deployment requirements are (supported OSes, existing installed applications, installation size, license terms on your software etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific framework for your desktop app ? If you use Qt for the GUI, you can also integrate javascript quite easily.

http://efforts.embedded.ufcg.edu.br/qt/?p=84

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use named pipes to pass data to a static page.

It might also be better to just make your c++ program into a simple web server which opens a port, and have it generate the web page when the user goes to http://localhost:8080.

Comment: There is no localhost as the app can't assume there is a webserver.