# Send large structure data from C++ to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, struct

I have an array of structure data:

```
struct DataValues
{
    int i_a;
    float f_b;
    char c_c;
};

struct DataValues dv_val[10000];
```

`dv_value` is calculated continuously in the C++ code.

I have some code in javascript to display this data in the browser using three.js.

I am unable to find a way to send the data from C++ to Javascript. I couldn't find other posts regarding sending large structure data from C++ to Javascript.

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from C++ application to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059147/how-to-pass-data-from-c-application-to-javascript)

Comment: Your question is too vague. How do your C++ and your JS program communicate eachother ? Standard I/O ? Another kind of I/O such as files or through the network ? DLL/DSO and JS FFI library ? Hardware ports ? Something else ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is regarding the communication between C++ and Javascript. Both files are in the same system. Since, the data that is to be transferred is large and has to be plotted continuously, I would not prefer files.

Comment: Just use protocol buffers and a TCP socket (if Node.js) or Websocket (if browser).

Comment: Could you point me to some examples for it?